# Extracting coordinates (x y z) from a BVH file

Tags: python, coordinates, bvh

I want to extract coordinates in x y z format from a BVH file.

I read about the rotational and transational matrices used in a BVH file but cannot make any sense out of it.

At last i want to make python script to extract these coordinates and them feed them to another python script which uses BPY for animation of a character in Blender.

Any kind of references in this context would help too.

Comment: Surely the importer / exporter as pointed out in  answer below does this?  IMO explaining the bvh file format  is bordering on off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of helpful information by taking a look at Blender's import and export scripts for BVH located in `/your/install/dir/2.80/scripts/addons/io_anim_bvh` or if you have cloned the repository `/your/git/repo/blender-git/blender/release/scripts/addons/io_anim_bvh` or [online in diffusion](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_anim_bvh/).

As you can see in the importer (line 173), the file contains so called channels which contain the x,y,z-coordinates. Since I'm not familiar with the format I can't tell you exactly how the matrix transformations work, but given that the importer script is rather short you may be able to figure this out on your own.